# Launching latest version of MonoDevelop on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: mono, ubuntu-14.04, monodevelop

I installed MonoDevelop using following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ermshiperete/monodevelop
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install monodevelop-current
```

because I wanted latest version.

```
sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```

results in installing 4.x version which I wasn't interested in.

Now I can launch application via terminal using:

```
/opt/monodevelop/bin/monodevelop-launcher.sh
```

but "monodevelop" command results in following information:

```
The program 'monodevelop' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install monodevelop
```

and creating monodevelop.desktop file doesn't result in having program icon in launcher. Any ideas what I should do to be able to run MonoDevelop using "monodevelop" command?

Answer (score 0):

> I installed MonoDevelop using following commands:
>   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ermshiperete/monodevelop`

Do you realize that when adding a repository, you're trusting this user (what he decides to package in his repository), and that the version you get is the one that he himself alone decided to package?

I recommend you to add the repository of the official developers/packagers instead. Follow the [instructions here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/) (but uninstall any old packages first).